# IEC62304 SOUP classification of Integrated Development Environments and compilers

Tags: software, standards

I am interested in whether IDEs, compilers or linkers are considered SOUP in IEC62304.  I found one [website](http://blog.cm-dm.com/post/2013/05/10/Got-SOUP-Part-1-Because-every-good-software-starts-with-SOUP) which claimed this is not the case.  I think I agree based on my reading of the standard, however, I would like to double check.

Comment: see [Discuss this ${blog}](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6418/31260)

Comment: @gnat This isn't about discussing someone's opinion. It's about a very specific term used in a regulated industry and compliance to a standard.

Comment: "I think I agree based on my reading of the standard". If this isn't expressing an opinion, then it's a legal interpretation of the wording of a standard. Either way, this question is off-topic.

Comment: @DavidArno Standards aren't laws. And since standards tend to be written in English (or other natural languages, all of which are full of ambiguities), people who have had to work to ensure IEC62304 compliance would be perfectly suited to answer. This question is totally on-topic here.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, I totally disagree that it's on topic. If it isn't a law question, then it's an opinion question. But it's clearly a question that interests you and so you have (mis)used your moderator powers to block our ability to close it, so I'll just move on and ignore it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any meaningful answer to the question of "is [a particular category of developer tool] SOUP" would also have to consider why one would want SOUP developer tools in the first place (i.e. for *safety* reasons).

From a practical standpoint, it is *the software being developed that must be safe,* not necessarily the tools used to develop it.  C and C++ are widely used to develop *safe* systems, despite the fact that any reasonable developer familiar with those languages would consider them quite unsafe.  You make them safe by following design techniques that render them safe, and by using compilers that fully comply with their respective language standards.

Conversely, it is still possible to use very safe languages like ADA and still have a system failure if you don't follow proper procedures, as the Ariane 5 explosion so effectively demonstrated.

So the question is not necessarily "are compilers considered SOUP," it is "is my particular compiler IEC62304 certified?"  From my reading of the standard, it seems to focus on rigorous software development processes, not development tools specifically.

[This article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c1c2bef2-4adb-403a-a1f9-f44952433541/iec-61508-european-safety-related-systems-certified-tool?forum=csharpide) asks *"Is Visual Studio / MS Build a certified tool under the BS/IEC 61508 British/European Standard?"*  The reply, in part, is:

> I think you misunderstand the "spheres" of IEC vs Visual Studio.  The IEC standard is a generalized specification for guaranteeing safety in some industries where safety is related to the control and operation of hardware (in combination with software) to ensure safe and reliable behavior.  This specification is the basis for more specific standards used in places like plant automation, oil and gas production and other safety critical environments.
>
> The [IEC] specification only lays out the the general characteristics that must exist in the process, hardware and software used to perform the necessary operations. [It] does not apply to [Visual Studio] or managed code **because they are solving two distinct problems.**

It further goes on to say that even the Windows Operating System itself "has never been (nor probably ever will be) a hard real-time OS, and that is generally a requirement for safety critical software."

So to answer your specific question, I don't think you can categorically state whether compilers as a whole are SOUP or not, because you would have to evaluate each compiler and its software development ecosystem independently of the others. Even if you could come up with a reasonable answer to that question, I'm not sure that it would be especially meaningful within the context of a standard that considers the rigor of your entire software development process important, not just your tools.

To put it another way, it's not the category of software (compilers, in this case) that makes it SOUP or not, it's the *manner in which it is developed.*

**Further Reading**
[Software of Unknown Pedigree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_of_unknown_pedigree)

Comment: Gah, beat me to the answer. The only thing that I question is that it is "not necessarily the tools used to develop it". Coming from an aerospace background, when you got into DO178 Levels A and B, your development tools (compilers, static analysis tools, etc.) did need to be certified at a certain level or meet minimum standards in order to be qualified. I'm not sure if IEC 62304 has any similar restrictions or content, but I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: The very last paragraph is the key, though.

Comment: Very good information and answer.  I agree with the last paragraph being key.

Comment: @ThomasOwens in aerospace also dev tools need to be certified?! I'm curious, is it a process you can apply to an existing tool or they must be designed from scratch with this certification in mind? Fortunately for 62304 the key point is the _objective evidence_ that the output of each design/development phase meet the requirements for that phase. If compiler output can be _verified_ then it's enough.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I'm not that familiar for the process for tool development. I do know that as the assurance level rose, the tools that could be used were limited because some tools were not properly certified or qualified. I also know that even non-production software produced internally for simulation, test, and development had to meet a set of criteria in order to be used to simulate or test software of a given assurance level. Most of the work I did was at very low design assurance levels, so I wasn't personally affected by a lot of these requirements.

Comment: @ThomasOwens thanks, wow that they're pretty though requests!

Answer (score 4):

While Robert's answer is very informative, I thought I'd provide a slightly different view.

The tools themselves (compiler, linker, etc.) are generally not considered SOUP, because they do not form part of the final software image that undergoes verification. They do, however, generate that image, and so you need to consider how much you trust those tools. Ask yourself these questions:

- How sure am I there are no bugs in this tool-chain that my affect my application?
- How would I know if there were any?
- What is the vendor's process for notifying about bugs found in the tools?

A risk-based analysis done in the context of the safety classification of the software system is appropriate here.

What **is** considered SOUP from your tool-chain vendor is anything source or object code provided by the vendor that makes it into the executable image. This includes the any runtime library implementation for your platform (e.g. the standard C library), as well as any startup code (e.g. for embedded platforms, the code that creates the C runtime environment). These need to be treated as SOUP according to the 62304 standard and the safety classification of the software.